# highlight name under list which by matching its content to a div id text

Tags: jquery, css

i have a un-ordered list like this

```
   <ul>
        <li id="projectrow_364"> 
            <span>Forest</span>
        </li>
        <li id="projectrow_365"> 
            <span>Life</span>
        </li>
        <li id="projectrow_367"> 
            <span>House</span>
        </li>
        <li id="projectrow_388"> Country
            <ul>
               <li id="projectrow_390"> 
               <span>US</span>
             </li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
   <ul>
```

And in the same page i have

```
<h3  id="project-title-id"> US</h3>
```

so i want to add this class name "`class="activeProject"`  " on above `<ul> li`  name where the text of  this #project-title-id matches  with `<ul> <li>` text value....
How to do this with jquery?

Comment: The OP doesn't have any code @Dave

Comment: @Dave Okay i am adding a fiddle, actually i have very big code in my project.

Comment: @Sundara Just the relevant code please.

Comment: There are two `<li>` elements that have `US` as a descendant. Which one (or both) should get the class?

Comment: @Dave  http://jsfiddle.net/4BBtu/

Comment: in html you have spaces (check h3 tag text), so you have to trim spaces too,, i dont think :contains will do that.. Do u basically want to loop through li and check for matching text

Comment: @Dave yes, i have nested `<li>` its a side bar menu in my project actually

Comment: check the code in fiddle,, http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/b37YG/3/ .. inspect with firebug and u will see class added.. is this what u need

Comment: here is update http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/b37YG/4/  .. is this what you are in need of,, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/VyBgu/

```
var currentHeader = $.trim( $('#project-title-id').html() );
var currentLI = $('li span:contains(' + currentHeader + ')');
currentLI.addClass('activeProject');
```

Comment: accurate solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides the `:contains` selector, which is case-sensitive:

```
var str = $('#project-title-id').text();
var li = $('ul li ul li:contains('+str+')');
li.addClass('activeProject');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/HCWm4/

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Sorry! you right , what you did is exactly the same. New thing `:contains` i am going to use in my project from now. thanks.

Comment: I think using `:contains` selector may have a different result other than the one the OP expects http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/HCWm4/1/ In such a case, maybe the OP wants the `USA` should not be considered as `activeProject`. However looks like in the situation of the OP, it can be used.